# squid transparent proxy on all ports

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, squid

I have setup squid as a transparent proxy by redirecting port 80 to the native squid port 3128. I know there are issues with getting secure ports like ssl and imaps to go though the proxy but can I redirect all other ports through the proxy as well. I am trying to get a better idea of bandwidth usage. I have setup iptables to log usage and i am getting most traffic going into the related/established rule. I am trying to determine the origins of this traffic by sending traffic to squid for more detailed logging.

Answer (score 1):

Redirecting traffic of all protocols to proxy server will not work especially for udp-based protocols.

If you want to implement traffic shapping to control bandwidth, you use 'tc'.

For logging, you can use iptables logging for simple things like initiating and terminating connection (matching specific rules). For more detailed logging, this requires speciallized software for packet inspection.

Comment: udp seems to be the culprit here as far as usage goes. I need to let the VOIP (SIP) system get through while droping anything else like Skype, Facetime and others... I tried as a test blocking all udp but the internet was not working. I think it might have been because of DNS on udp 53. Would this make sense? I might try this solution again if you think it might have been the cause of not being able to browse. I have both VOIP handsets setup as static ips so I can let then though specifically after when i have this working.

Answer (score 0):

Squid isn't going to help you monitor non-HTTP traffic. I would suggest using iptables to count traffic based on protocol and port numbers.

In terms of allowing SIP but not other VoIP protocols, you probably want a deny-by-default firewall which then allows traffic on certain ports (DNS, SIP, HTTP, etc.). Note that some clients like Skype are very good at bypassing firewalls like this by finding allowed ports and using those.